# Widgets not showing

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, widgets, widget, widget-instance

I'm trying to create a simple widget that for example gets displayed on every site, but I can't get the widget to show. I'm also trying to add a standard Magento widget, but that doesn't work neither. I'm adding the widget under CMS->widgets, for the theme I tried default/default and also base/default, I tried to change the current shop theme and tried different layout locations but the widget doesn't show up. My cache ist deactivated and empty. I'm only able to add the widget in the editor on a new page, where it gets correctly displayed.
What might be the problem?

Comment: In CMS->widgets, which type you have selected?

Answer (score 0):

Hey try out this well explained tutorial for create custom widget :-

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-widget-development-in-magento--cms-23015